# Позиционирование блоков

Tags: css

Не знаю кому как, но мне данная задачка показалась сложноватой, ибо знания css не сильно велики. В общем задача, есть 2 блока:

```
 _______________
| 1 | 2 | пусто |
|1.1|           |
|1.2|           |
|1.3|           |
```

При большом разрешении экрана должно быть так, как на схеме выше. При уменьшении размера окна браузера или при разрешении экрана, например, меньше 1280px схема должна быть такой:

```
 _______________
| 2 |   пусто   |
 ---------------
| 1  1.1 1.2 1.3|
```

Т.е. блок 2 смещается влево, а блок 1 располагается под ним. В блоке 1 несколько div'ов, которые в 1-м случае располагаются в столбик, а во 2-м случае в строке.

Может есть у кого идей на этот счет, буду признателен...

P.S. на поддержку старых браузеров начхать.

P.P.S. блок 1 - имеет фиксированную ширину в 200px

**UPDATE**

Если будет проще, то давайте возьмем все фиксированной ширины, кроме разрешения.

```
Блок 1 - 200px,
Блок 2 - 900px.
```

И еще раз опишу, надо чтоб все прижималось к левому краю, но при уменьшении разрешения чтоб 1-й блок уходил под 2-й, а не наоборот.

Comment: Я бы в таком случае написал бы скрипт, который всё бы раставлял. Хотя знаю, что это и не правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

смотреть в сторону адаптивный и мобильный дизайн с CSS3 Media Queries.
Вот тебе пару ссылок

- [Как использовать медиа запросы CSS3 чтобы создать версию вашего сайта для мобильных устройств](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=698);
- [Дизайн для мобилок и CSS3 медиа запросы](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=1177).

Comment: если бы во 2-м случае надо было бы чтоб 2-й блок располагался под 1-м - это пару минут работы, а проблема как раз в том, что они должны поменяться местами при уменьшении размера экрана. Пробовал делать float:left у блока 1 и через @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) float:right у блока 2, тогда все работает как надо, только вот проблема, если разрешение экрана очень большое, то левый блок прижат к левому краю, правый - к правому, а посередине большая "дырка"

Comment: ну а ты сделай если ширина еще больше то опять поменяй дизайн.

Comment: А например? При разрешении 1400 пикс. все отлично отображается, левый слева, правый справа (т.к. флоаты), при уменьшении разрешения у правого убираем флоат и все. А что делать тогда при увеличении разрешения, чтоб между правым и левым блоками не появлялся огромный пробел?

Comment: сменить ширину блока(родителю можно уменьшить и тогда дырки такой не будет).

Comment: да не, это не выход. блок 2 прижат с помощью float:right - это "костыль", который я поставил из-за недостаточных знаний css, так быть точно не должно, все должно прижиматься к левому краю. Потому и ширину обертки в зависимости от разрешения задавать незачем.
upd.вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Мой ответ, скорее можно считать оффтоп, но думаю, что может пригодиться на будущее. Статьи вы конечено почитайте, т.к. некоторые моменты просто надо знать. А я подскажу вам предельно простой способ, который пришел мне сразу же на ум, как только я начал делать свою первую адаптивную верстку. Создав стили под обычное разрешение экрана, я убирал все основные стили разметки, изменял размер браузера до нужного мне и писал стили уже так, как бы я хотел видеть расположение блоков в данном случае. Далее сравнивал оба стиля для каждого блока, определял те, которые не изменились и под праилом [[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media), оставлял стили, которые относятся именно к уменьшенному разрешению.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, обязательно учту на будущее!

Answer (score 1):

Если вас озадачивает не предвидено очень большое разрешение экрана, то не проще ли добавить **max- width**, тем более что у вас уже есть **min-width**.

Answer (score 1):

А как Вам идея создать 3 блока: "пусто", "2" и "1" все с float:right, все кроме первого - фиксированной ширины.. У блока "пусто" цвет под фон бодобрать и ширину 180px (?), а чтобы "1" не отрывался от левого края - сунуть их все в 4-й блок шириной в 1280px, и прижать влево float-ом или спозиционировать..